# Wrapping a pointer in Go

Tags: pointers, go, dereference

A library `foo` exposes a type `A` and a function `Fn` in that library returns a `*A`.

I have defined a "wrapper" for `A` called `B`:

```
type B foo.A
```

Can I convert the `*A` to a `*B` without dereferencing the `A`?

In other words, if I have

```
a := foo.Fn()   // a is a *A
b := B(*a)
return &b
```

How can I convert the `*a` to a `*b` without using `*a`?

The reason that I ask is that in the library that I am using, `github.com/coreos/bbolt`, the `*DB` value returned from the `Open` function includes a `sync.Mutex` and so the compiler complains when I try to make a copy of the `Mutex`.

**UPDATE TO EXPLAIN HOW I'LL USE THIS**

I have a

```
type Datastore struct {
    *bolt.DB
}
```

I also have a function (one of many) like this:

```
func (ds *Datastore) ReadOne(bucket, id string, data interface{}) error {
    return ds.View(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
        b, err := tx.CreateBucketIfNotExists([]byte(bucket))
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("opening bucket %s: %v", bucket, err)
        }

        bytes := b.Get([]byte(id))
        if bytes == nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("id %s not found", id)
        }

        if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, data); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("unmarshalling item: %v", err)
        }

        return nil
    })
}
```

I would like to mock the underlying BoltDB database using a hash map. I ran into a problem mocking this because of the `View` expecting a function that takes `bolt.Tx`. That `tx` is then used to create a new bucket in `CreateBucketIfNotExists`. I cannot replace that anonymous function argument with one that calls my hash map mock version of `CreateBucketIfNotExists`.

I came up with this:

```
package boltdb

import (
    "github.com/coreos/bbolt"
)

type (
    bucket bolt.Bucket

    // Bucket is a wrapper for bolt.Bucket to facilitate mocking.
    Bucket interface {
        ForEach(fn func([]byte, []byte) error) error
        Get(key []byte) []byte
        NextSequence() (uint64, error)
        Put(key, value []byte) error
    }

    db bolt.DB

    // DB is a wrapper for bolt.DB to facilitate mocking.
    DB interface {
        Close() error
        Update(fn func(*Tx) error) error
        View(fn func(*Tx) error) error
    }

    transaction bolt.Tx

    // Tx is a wrapper for bolt.Tx to facilitate mocking.
    Tx interface {
        CreateBucketIfNotExists(name []byte) (Bucket, error)
    }
)

// ForEach executes a function for each key/value pair in a bucket.
func (b *bucket) ForEach(fn func([]byte, []byte) error) error {
    return ((*bolt.Bucket)(b)).ForEach(fn)
}

// Get retrieves the value for a key in the bucket.
func (b *bucket) Get(key []byte) []byte {
    return ((*bolt.Bucket)(b)).Get(key)
}

// NextSequence returns an autoincrementing integer for the bucket.
func (b *bucket) NextSequence() (uint64, error) {
    return ((*bolt.Bucket)(b)).NextSequence()
}

// Put sets the value for a key in the bucket.
func (b *bucket) Put(key, value []byte) error {
    return ((*bolt.Bucket)(b)).Put(key, value)
}

// Close releases all database resources.
func (db *db) Close() error {
    return ((*bolt.DB)(db)).Close()
}

// Update executes a function within the context of a read-write managed transaction.
func (db *db) Update(fn func(Tx) error) error {
    return ((*bolt.DB)(db)).Update(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
        t := transaction(*tx)
        return fn(&t)
    })
}

// View executes a function within the context of a managed read-only transaction.
func (db *db) View(fn func(Tx) error) error {
    return ((*bolt.DB)(db)).View(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
        t := transaction(*tx)
        return fn(&t)
    })
}

// CreateBucketIfNotExists creates a new bucket if it doesn't already exist.
func (tx *transaction) CreateBucketIfNotExists(name []byte) (Bucket, error) {
    b, err := ((*bolt.Tx)(tx)).CreateBucketIfNotExists(name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    w := bucket(*b)
    return &w, nil
}
```

So far, in my code, I am only using the functions shown above. I can add more if new code requires.

I will replace each `bolt.DB` with `DB`, `bolt.Tx` with `Tx`, and `bolt.Bucket` with `Bucket` in the real code. The mocker will use replacements for all three types that use the underlying hash map instead of storing to disk. I can then test all of my code, right down to the database calls.

Comment: You can directly convert them, but the odd thing here is _why_ are you making the type `B` in the first place? It's not "wrapping" `foo.A`, it's removing the method set.

Comment: I am trying to write a mock for the underlying database for unit testing.

Comment: Not sure how that's going to mock anything, since it still requires the original type. You're probably better off composing the type you want in your own data structure.

Comment: Check out my updated explanation of how I will use this. If you can suggest a better way, I'm interested in hearing about it.

Comment: Normally you use embedding (ie composition) for this, so you don’t need to stub out every method call.

Comment: Yes, but in this specific case, with `CreateBucketIfNotExists`, how would that work? What type would `CreateBucketIfNotExists` return?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you can still fulfill your interfaces with composed types. The fundamental issue here is that declaring a new type based on a struct from another package does nothing to decouple you from that package, still requires you to stub out all the exiting methods, and you need and tread very carefully around the copying values. For example (warning, just typed this out without verifying anything): https://play.golang.org/p/LBVcXkm31gi

Comment: I understand now what you meant. I've reworked my code using the BoltDB types inside structs and it is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply / directly convert a value of type `*A` to a value of type `*B`, you just have to parenthesize `*B`:

```
a := foo.Fn()   // a is a *A
b := (*B)(a)
return b
```

You can even convert the return value of the function call:

```
return (*B)(foo.Fn())
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-FsplkpYfKy).

This is possible, because [Spec: Conversions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> A non-constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` in any of these cases:
>
> - `x` is [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to `T`.
> - ...

And [Spec: Assignability:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)

> A value `x` is assignable to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - ...
> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) type.

Both `*B` and `*A` types are not defined, and the underlying type of `*B` is the same as the underlying type of `*A` (which is the pointer to the underlying type of whatever type there is in the type declaration of `A`).

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I tried several combinations, but none compiled. Thanks.